# How would I get codeigniter2 to accept command line interface urls from its index file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line

I have placed the following code at the top of index.php:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
    $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = implode('/', $argv) . '/';
}
```

Ive also hard coded the **$system_path** var to:
**"/Users/derrick/Sites/website/system";**

as well as the **$application_folder** to 
**"/Users/derrick/Sites/website/admin";**

I then run the following command from terminal:

> php
>   /Users/derrick/Sites/website/index.php
>   user email

I then a get the normal CI page not found error, can anyone tell me why?
*(http://localhost/~derrick/website/index.php/user/email works from the normal browser)*

*Please note that this is for CI 2 and not CI 1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do? Command line interaction works fine out of the box if you are cd'ed to the level of your index file without any changed.

```
php index.php controller method param1 param2
```

I have made a few changes after 2.0.0 which will go into 2.0.1 to allow this to work from any directory (to help crontab etc) so you can grab this if you know what you are doing on BitBucket, but still you don't need  to mess around with any server variables to get it working.

Comment: I started this project on an early version of the CI 2 release from bitBucket. (Probably the "core" version), Ive also got wanWizards HMVC extensions installed. Ive just tested it on CI reactor as well and it works as expected. (will have to move everything over.) Thanks Phil, you guys are doing great job with CI.

Comment: Sorry thats wiredesignz HMVC extension.

Comment: Update: upgraded to CI reactor but it seems as tho the HMVC extension interferes with the working command line part of reactor, trying to find a way of disabling HMVC for command line calls.

Comment: I'll have a look into why HMVC is breaking it if I can, PyroCMS uses both so will be annoying if not working. If wiredesignz won't accept my patch (he never does) I'll supply you with a link to my fork.

Comment: Great thx Phil, Im not sure that this is an HMVC problem anymore. I reported it as a bug on bitBucket: https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/issue/85/

Comment: I saw this and your other question, but is it the same issue? Either parameters are not being sent or database is not working. Do you have an example of code that fails, as this is just loading the database library and nothing to do with returning data. I can't help if you post a million conflicting things in a million places. I read it all anyway so lets just have a talk here. :)

Comment: These are the steps Ive taken: Took a fresh copy of CI Reactor, put in my database settings, opened up welcome.php in controllers and created two hello functions, one with the database driver been loaded and one without.

Opened up terminal and typed in:
/opt/local/bin/php /Users/derrick/sites/CIReactor/index.php welcome hello -->

prints out hello inside terminal, then I tried:


/opt/local/bin/php /Users/derrick/sites/CIReactor/index.php welcome helloDriver -->

No longer prints out hello

Comment: Phil, I am having an issue with wiredesignz HMVC as well.. i can run the command line using regular CI2.0 Controller but when I try to run the module, it doesn't work.. I get 404 error.. any ideas?